# fetchRequest question

Tags: iphone, core-data

in core data , I search using fetchRequest and predicate like the following

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
             entityForName:@"Study"
    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                @"( StudyID == %@ )",self.StudyID]];

NSArray * StudyList  = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

how to check if there a return values or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
if(!StudyList){
    //handle fetch request error here
} else {
    //success! 
    if([StudyList count] > 0){ //if array not empty
        //do stuff with StudyList contents here
        NSLog(@"StudyList contents: %@", StudyList);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This won't work because the fetch can return an empty array if no objects match the predicate. You only get a nil if you get an active error and simply not finding any matches is not an error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I obviously assumed the OP would be able to take it from there, but I changed my answer to better address an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You check the size of the `StudyList` array like so:

```
if ([StudyList count]>0){
    //... found at least one Study object
}else{
    //... didn't find anything
}
```

As an aside, you should follow the naming conventions. A variable like `StudyList` should be written starting with lower case i.e. `studyList`. By convention, names that start with capital letters indicate some sort of constant e.g. classes, entities, constants etc.

Comment: I agree with the comment on naming conventions, however (to AMH) it is vital that you implement error handling rather than merely checking for an empty array. Do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the documentation of the method:

> If an error occurs, returns nil. If no
>   objects match the criteria specified
>   by request, returns an empty array.

Comment: This does not check for an empty return but just whether an error occurred. A fetch will return an empty array if it does not find any objects that match the predicate or if not objects of the entity exist in the object graph.

Comment: @TechZen I don't really get your point. Isn't what you said identical to what is stated in the documentation?